# Trans case on 1999 Dodge Ram noise

Tags: noise, dodge, 4wd, ram, transfer

I have a 1999 Dodge Ram 1500 5.2l V8. And I am hearing a chain like noise when at higher speeds (50mph+.. of course in 2wd) after I left off of the gas and when I step on the gas.

The noise is almost like a chain tightening when I give it gas and loosening when I left off. I have a np231d transfer case and am wondering if it's a loos chain in the case? What do you all think? And how can I fix this? thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's coming from the transfer case?  A chain rattling is a good description of a sound, but there are many things that can sound like that and this noise probably isn't coming from a chain.

Comment: Have you checked your u-joints?

Comment: Zack, I am just guessing, but that's where the sound sounds like it's been coming from. But that's why I'm asking y'all here because I don't know for sure. @Paulster2 I have checked u-joints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out to be the transfer case chain. It was loose and just needed to be replaced.